# How to get content with format from clipboard

Tags: python, google-chrome, clipboard

guys.

When i copy some words from internet using Chrome and paste to the Office Words, Words remind me that I can paste the words keeping source format.
***That means clipboard can contain both the plain text and its format?***

Meanwhile, I am writing an app using Python to get the content of clipboard. But don't know how to get the content format.

```
import Tkinter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r=Tkinter.Tk()
    r.withdraw()
    print r.clipboard_get()
    r.destroy()
```

BTW, my app is running on Win7.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2):

The clipboard does contain data in multiple formats.  Typically, you've got TEXT/UnicodeText, RTF, and HTML.
See [MSDN List of standard formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). and [HTML Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to don't write your own tool when there are existing modules doing the same. Try: http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/

Comment: pyperclip doesn't allow HTML for example